# "okay" vs "good" in questions starting with "Is it okay/good"

Tags: word-usage

Is it better to use "good" instead of "okay" in question starting with "Is it okay/good", or isn't? For example,

> Is it okay/good to eat tonight?

> Is it okay/good to break the rules?
>   <sub>(I know it isn't)</sub>

Comment: I think you need to provide some context here. If someone told me "I'm going to have to punish you for breaking the rules," I'd definitely say "okay" instead of "good".

Comment: @DigitalChris yep.

Comment: In my opinion, they are not synonymous. Okay implies allowability. Good implies a value judgement. How you use them depends on what you mean to say. I would use okay to ask, perhaps, *Is it okay if we eat early tonight?* and "When is it *okay* to break the rules? When is it *good*? The first asks when is it allowable. The second  asks when it it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to ask.

*Is it okay?* is like asking *Is it acceptable?* or *Is it permissible?*

*Is it good?* is like asking *Is it desirable?* or *Is it enjoyable?*

Comment: But "It isn't good" can mean "It isn't acceptable/permissible", can't it?

Comment: @nicael do you have an example?

Comment: Example - "It isn't good".

Comment: uh, an example perhaps, where we know what 'it' is.

Comment: @Neil I think if you edited your answer to also reflect the differing uses in response to a question, your point might be clearer. E.g. If someone asks you 'What do you think about that teacher?' Answering 'They're okay' implies that they are just sufficient, but answering 'They're good' states they are desirable.

Comment: @nicael 'It isn't good (...to throw stones at cars)'. You are blending two meanings of good here. 'good' can refer to whether something is desirable or enjoyable, as Neil indicated, or it can be a moral judgement (good vs evil). The sentence 'it isn't good' would be valid if you were asked to make a judgement on desirability (someone asked you how the food tasted) but would be considered insufficient in most cases when referring to an action 'Why can't I throw stones at people?' Here you should 'It isn't good/acceptable/permissible because ...' or to use 'It is wrong' instead.